# Get current position from mapbox unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, location, mapbox

I've just started programming in Unity 3D and i wanted to create a map similar to the google map application for android. My problem is that I'm trying to create a button to go back to the current gps position in my map. How can i get the current posizion and use it as a center in my map?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use one of the `LocationProvider` components. They all derive from `AbstractLocationProvider` and have a `CurrentLocation` variable. Get your LatLon coordinates from there and convert them to Unity world space using [one of the conversion methods](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-unity-sdk/api/unity/Mapbox.Unity.Utilities.Conversions.html). Then just move your camera to this position.